# Passing a cart total variable to Paypal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal

When implementing Paypal I have managed to set it up to send a set value such as £25 however not a variable from the basket e.g. 'GrandTotal' which is dependent on what the customer has entered into the cart (I have created my own cart.)

```
<form action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00"> 
<input type="image" src="paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif"; name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"> </form>
```

Do you know how to send the variable rather than a set amount? Is the code below anywhere near a solution?

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="GrandTotal">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make input field server side by adding runat="server" in input field tag and can set it value from .cs file

field.value=GrandTotal;

Your aspx page code

```
<form name="_xclick" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
method="post" runat="server">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" runat="server" />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/view_cart.gif" border="0"
    name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
</form>
```

Your code behind page code 
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

        amount.Value = "25.25";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Sorry but I am an absolute novice, I do not understand what to do in the .cs file, could you expand please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert your `form tag` in ASP.Net page (unless iframe), because ASP.Net only allows one form tag in a page.

You want similar like this in code behind. It basically collect user entered Amount and Quantity, and then post it back to PayPal.

```
protected void PayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

 string paypalUrl = IsTestMode ? 
   "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" : 
   "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr";

 var builder = new StringBuilder();

 builder.Append(paypalUrl);

 builder.AppendFormat("?cmd=_xclick&business={0}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(you@youremail.com));

 builder.Append("&lc=US&no_note=0&currency_code=GBP");

 builder.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YourItemName));

 builder.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", AmountTextBox.Text);

 builder.AppendFormat("&return={0}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://mysite.cm/ReturnUrl"));

 builder.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", 
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://mysite.cm/CancelUrl"));

 builder.AppendFormat("&undefined_quantity={0}", QuantityTextBox.Text);

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(builder.ToString());

}
```